# Codeigniter passing multiple checked parameters back to the view

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, parameter-passing, multiple-value

I new to CI, and in doubt of how to passing params, my scenario is:

1) A form with multiple checkbox, seen as **online_booking.php**, user would checked multiple options.

2) User click button to call jq ajax post in json, this will get the callback params from **booking_process** in controller.

3) the returned results will then print on the view in `#result` div block.

OK, above process is worked fine and the result is print like what user's has checked.

Now is my problem, I want to re-use the callback result in view, even I have the result printed on the view page, but I can't use the result for further processing, how could I make the returned results into a variable in view?

I had try few way, I try the old fashion with `online_booking?selected=mutipleCheckedValue&sum=500` passing method with changed of $config['permitted_uri_chars'], but get only the last checked value instead of all checked values, which is means even I checked the checkbox with Type A+B+C, in the URL its only show value for Type C, I know this is not a good practice in CI but may help  to solve my doubt if I couldn't find a proper solution.

I even try to store checked values in session, as seen on controller, `$this->session->set_userdata('selected', $conf_type.":".$conf_charge);`, its still only show the last checked value.

Please give an advise on how to overcome with this issue as I already stucked in this part plenty of time.

**online_booking.php View:**

```
<?php
$is_logged = $this->simplelogin->is_logged();
$active = $this->simplelogin->get_data_user('activate');
$user_email = $this->simplelogin->get_data_user('email');

if(!$is_logged) {

    echo "<p>Please login to get access</p>";

}else if($active == 0){
    echo "<p>Your account is inactive to proceed this page</p>";

}else{

?>

<p><h2>Online Booking</h2></p>

<p><div id="result_msg"></div></p>

<p>
<form id="conf_booking_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cType[]" value="A,200">&nbsp;Type A - USD200<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cType[]" value="B,150">&nbsp;Type B - USD150<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cType[]" value="C,100">&nbsp;Type C - USD100<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cType[]" value="D,50">&nbsp;Type D - USD50<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_email" value="<?php echo $user_email ?>" />
    <input type="button" id="btn_conf" name="" value="Book" />
    <span id="wait"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/loader.gif" /></span><br />
</form>
</p>
<p><div id="result" style="color:#606;"></div></p>

<?php
}
?>
```

**JQuery ajax post:**

```
$('#btn_conf').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#conf_booking_form').serialize();

    //alert(parameters);
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'site/booking_process',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_str){
            if(output_str == "false"){
                $('#result_msg').html("Select at least one type to proceed booking");

            }else{
                $('#result').html(output_str);
                //window.location.replace(baseurl + 'site/online_booking?selected='+output_str.selected+'&sum='+output_str.sum);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

public function online_booking() {
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('online_booking');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function booking_process(){
    $confTypes = $this->input->post('cType');
    $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');
    $output_str = NULL;
    $conf_charge_total = 0;

    if(!empty($confTypes)){

        foreach($confTypes as $confType){
            $explode_value = explode(",", $confType);

            $conf_type = $explode_value[0];
            $conf_charge = $explode_value[1];

            $conf_charge_total += $conf_charge; //sum up checked values

            $output_str .= $conf_type.":".$conf_charge.",";
            /*$output_str = array(
                    'selected' => $conf_type.','.$conf_charge,
                    'email' => $user_email,
                    'sum' => $conf_charge_total,
                    'flag' => 'true'
                );*/

            //$this->session->set_userdata('selected', $conf_type.":".$conf_charge);
        }

        $output_str .= $conf_charge_total;

        //$this->session->set_userdata('sum_conf_charges', $conf_charge_total);

    }else{
        $output_str = "false";
    }

    echo json_encode($output_str);
}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store `set_userdata('selected', ...)` inside the loop, `selected` will be overwritten each time you loop. This results in the last value stored, as you observed. You can move this out of the loop, either before or after, and

```
$this->session->set_userdata('selected', $confTypes);
```

or prepare an array and store that

```
foreach ($confTypes as $confType){
    ...
    $selected_conf_types[$conf_type] = $conf_charge;
}

$this->session->set_userdata('selected', $selected_conf_types);
```

Comment: @conmen I'm not familiar with CI, but I think you can always use curl, if you want to load an URL.